# MDX - Meaning of a variable number in front of category,Member?

Tags: sql, ssas, mdx, cube

I'm new to MDX and reading the manual at Microsoft about MDX queries.
Unfortunately, I don't know anyone in person to ask this stupid question but does a number in front of the Category in the dimension property have any meaning? ([60FISCPER], [20CUSTOMER] ) 
I looked at the manual if this is a short version of any function like "*" instead of a cross join, but couldn't find an answer.

This is the query I have, but no access to SSAS to experiment with.

```
SELECT {
    [B2007SMUPKMPGBI14TQTR5U9].[EU74ZOEZI11PJWY2BX3HRV404],
    [B2007SMUPKMPGBI14TQTR5U9].[EU74ZOEZI11PJWY2BX3HRVAB4],
    [B2007SMUPKMPGBI14TQTR5U9].[EU74ZOEZI11PJWY2BX3HRVKR4]}
ON COLUMNS,
    NON EMPTY
    [0FISCPER].[LEVEL01].MEMBERS *
    [0CALDAY].[LEVEL01].MEMBERS *
    [0CRM_PRCTYP].[LEVEL01].MEMBERS *
    [0CRM_OBJ_ID].[LEVEL01].MEMBERS *
    [0CUSTOMER].[LEVEL01].MEMBERS
    DIMENSION PROPERTIES
    [0FISCPER].[60FISCPER],
    [0CUSTOMER].[20CUSTOMER],
    [0CRM_PRCTYP].[20CRM_PRCTYP]
ON ROWS
FROM [CA_RED01M/AT_Q_P_CA_RED01_0100]
WHERE ( [CREDQTYP].[#])
SAP VARIABLES [!V000001] INCLUDING [0CALDAY].[@[User::sFromDate]] [!V000002] INCLUDING [0CALDAY].[@[User::sToDate]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The text inside the square brackets are the names of objects in your OLAP cube, so nothing to do with the MDX language.

If in your cube you have a level called “Country” then to use it within an MDX script you put square brackets around it ‘[Country]’  with no additional numbers.